# sha1() for Password hashing

Tags: php

I am using sha1 for my password security. I have stored password in this way in register.php

```
// secure password
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
$secured_password = sha1($password . $salt);

//Send it to mysql table
$result = $access->registerUser($username, $secured_password, $salt, $email, $fullname);
```

This all is working fine.

Problem is here:

In my login.php

```
 $password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$secure_password = $user["password"];
$salt = $user["salt"];


// 4.2 Check if entered passwords match with password from database
if ($secure_password == sha1($password . $salt)) {
//do something 
} else {

//do something
 }
```

I am always getting as password does not match.
where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why not jsut use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`? It's much easier to use.

Comment: @Nytrix : I tried password_hash() I am getting error while saving password.

Comment: @Spurti what php version are u on?

Comment: DON'T USE SHA-1 FOR PASSWORD HASHING!  It is no longer considered secure

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  PHP 7

Comment: so whats the error where u getting on `password_hash()`

Comment: @Spurti - so if you get an error saving passwords with password_hash(), better to fix that error than revert to using an insecure sha1 (which is also giving you problems)

Comment: Though why do you believe you need to do `$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);` at all?

Comment: @MarkBaker Then how do you fetch password from user ?

Comment: You don't munglulate the entered password by running htmlentities() on it; reduces entropy, changes the password from what the user entered, serves no useful purpose

Comment: @Spurti see [Don't escape password/ use any cleansing machenism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628418/cleansing-user-passwords/36628423#36628423)  Doing so changes what the user enters

Comment: I tried $secure_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) ;  It fails to save on Mysql table.

Comment: And that line gave you an error? Or saving it gave you an error? What error did you get?

Comment: @MarkBaker that is exactly what I asked him [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864666/sha1-for-password-hashing#comment74764726_43864666)

Comment: while saving it gives me error , saying failed to insert into Table

Comment: The response should also give you a reason why the save failed; check logs, ensure that you're getting the full reason; check column size in your table.... fix that error, but don't revert to using insecure password hashing

Comment: what makes you think that is caused by `password_hash()` at @Spurti

Comment: If you can't save the output from password_hash() then it's not password_hash() that's at fault, it's either your schema or your insert/update statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First is first. **NEVER USE SHA OR MCRYPT TO STORE YOUR PASSWORD**.

**EDIT** : The `password_hash()` function generates a long password hash, so make sure that your column in the mysql is a `VARCHAR` of 500 space

All these useless practises is the root reason why almost many websites get hacked. To tackle the situation, php did a lot of research and then at last came with the most secure function called the `password_hash()`. I am not more onto explaining about `password_hash()` here as there are already many documents on the internet.

You can always hash a password like this

```
<?php

$securePassword = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query = $db->query('INSERT INTO users ......');

?>
```

And, to verify the password, you can simply use this function

```
<?php

$passwordHash = $query['password']; //Password from database
$userPassword = $_POST['password']; //Password from form

if(password_verify($userPassword, $passwordHash)) {
    echo 'Password is correct, logged in!';
} else {
    echo 'Password is wrong, try again';
}

?>
```

---

And, answer for your question.

***PLEASE DON'T USE SHA OR MCRYPT OR BCRYPT. IF YOU WANNA GET YOUR WEBSITE HACKED, THEN CONTINUE. OR USE `password_hash()`***

The reason you don't get the hash genereated each time because the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` generates random numbers each time. So each time, during execution, the function returns different numbers and you get your `sha` result wrong and thus giving a `FALSE` alert.

**PLEASE, AGAIN. I BEG YOU TO USE `password_hash()` FUNCTION**

---

For more information on `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` :

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: You are welcome @Spurti. I am just 15yrs old. Any help? Comment down here :)

Comment: very impressive from a 15 year :) big up

Comment: Actually, password_hash is using bcrypt. Also, what's the relation between a website getting hacked and using "weak" (once again, it's not proved) hashing algorithm? And, maybe 500 is a bit too much, even the documentation recommand 255.

Comment: Well, I merely agree with you @Sakuto. But, as the test reveals, the password_hash() function is the most secure way of hashing password in this era (or at least in PHP7). And, about the relation matter, I agree with you :)

Comment: Password given to password_hash is truncated to 72 characters. And no, it won't give you 500 character long string, it will always be 60 characters in length.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that. Merely, to accept, I was kind of lazy to search the exact length of `password_hash` @mike

Comment: The recommendation is a VARCHAR(255). While the current hash is only 60 characters long, if the default algorithm changes with a new version of PHP, then that length might change